# Transfering data from one database to another using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small project which requires to transfer data from one database to another. Both databases are identical and one database in the web hosting server and other is in my local computer. On a web page in the hosting server I am going to show a table with a import link as below,

[image]

When I click the import button all the related data of a customer should be imported in to the database which running in my local computer.
I need to develop this application using PHP. Is it possible to do this directly without exporting the required data into a file at the hosting server and importing that file at the local computer. Your comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems are you encoutering? What limitations do you have? What is your home setup? Is your home machine visible on the web? Does your publicly visible home IP address change? What is your experience with various web technologies? etc. We're not going to write your code for you - we're the last resort when you have exhausted _all_ avenues.

Comment: mysql replication, or simply mysqldump

Comment: is it something related to file upload

Comment: I thought to send the client computers' web IP address to the hosting server and using that IP update the database of the local machine. I am not expecting any codes. I just need to know two things, is this possible and if so what sort of steps I should proceed.

Comment: noup, it is importing some data from a remote database to the local computer which has identical databses.

Comment: Of course it's possible. Everything is possible in some way or another. You will need to create a mysql login with access from a specific IP address and then create a PHP script to run as an AJAX responder (which is how I would do it). You've just got to work out how to get your target machine's  IP address across to the hosted site and into the responder, all the security, are you sending customer sensitive data in plain text across the web, what are the security concerns, injection problems, how are you going to prevent someone calling your AJAX responder with a fake target etc. Have fun

Comment: before client see the customer data page, client should login to the site. then client can navigate to the page as shown in above image.

Comment: How secure are the client passwords? Are they easily crackable using a dictionary? etc. Just one question - why are you actually doing the transfer across to your local machine? If it's only you who needs to import the data, couldn't you just use a nightly DB dump and import that the next morning? If it's for development purposes, I would knock up some fake data so that there is no risk of customer's data being compromised - your hosted site may be secure but what about your home machine?

Answer (score 0):

If you have public IP address for you local machine you can do it easily.

1. Select data from web database save it in memory
2. Connect to your local database by public IP
3. Insert data from memory to your local database

But be careful with record id. If user adds new records to local database and you try to add fixed id record then there may be a conflict.

Comment: does public ip means the IP address we are obtaining when we connect to the internet?

Comment: It means you can reach your computer from internet. You can read about it [here](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/workingwithipaddresses/f/what-is-a-public-ip-address.htm).